# Changing Rubber on a Ping Pong Paddle

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket

I have a ping pong paddle with one side that has sandpaper grip and another paddle with a nicer rubber that unfortunately is broken.

I want to put the rubber from the broken paddle on the paddle with the sandpaper rubber. Is there an *easy* way to change the rubber on a ping pong paddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the following items:

- Heat Gun (a hair dryer would suffice also)
- Spray Adhesive

---

To remove rubber from a side of a ping-pong paddle:

1. Use the heat gun to warm the adhesive between the rubber and the paddle.
2. When the adhesive is warm enough, **slowly** begin to remove the rubber.

   - If your attempt to remove the rubber is of any trouble, repeat step 1.
   - It is important **not** to tear the rubber in any way, shape, or form.

Optional: If clunky remains of adhesive remain on either the paddle or rubber, you may use the heat gun to warm and slowly attempt to remove the adhesive.

---

To apply new rubber to a side of a ping-pong paddle (assuming old rubber has been removed):

1. Evenly apply spray adhesive to the paddle (assuming there are no clunky remains of adhesive are present).
2. Evenly apply the backside of the rubber onto the paddle.
3. Give the adhesive an adequate amount of time to bond between the rubber and paddle.

   - Applying weight to the applicable side of the rubber/paddle may accelerate the process.

Comment: Do you know of anywhere I could find an appropriate adhesive? @edmastermind29

Comment: This may be an [appropriate adhesive](http://www.amazon.com/Donic-Formula-First-table-tennis/dp/B003A2CLHK/ref=sr_1_5?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1375880640&sr=1-5&keywords=table+tennis+glue). Personally, I would be satisfied with a general purpose spray adhesive with better than normal bond.