# Alternative to table tennis glue?

Tags: equipment, table-tennis, racket, maintenance

The rubber of my table tennis bat is starting to peel off one "corner".

Are there any household products I can use to stick it back that will not damage the rubber too much?

Comment: I would use a spray adhesive. I go into that in [this answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/2898) about changing the rubber of a paddle.

Answer (score 1):

Many players I know, including myself, use Rubber Cement.  It's cheaper than the "Chack" you get from Stiga, Butterfly, etc, and in my experience, seems to work just as well.  It also doesn't leave any bits of the rubber on the blade when you need to remove it.

Just spread a thin layer on the blade and rubber surface, let it dry, then attach them.  These are the 2 that I've been using for many years.

[image]
[image]

Comment: One of the reasons TT recently moved to water based glue was to eliminate the exposure of players to harmful vapours from glues containing VOC's.
The glues you have recommended are against the rules of Table Tennis and we therefore shouldn't be advocating their use